# Mono gtk.RadioButton Clicked event firing twice

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I have a problem with the `Gtk.RadioButton` widget's `Clicked` event.
Here is the example code:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{   
    public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build ();
        RadioButton rbt1 = new RadioButton (null, "rbt1");
        RadioButton rbt2 = new RadioButton (rbt1, "rbt2");
        RadioButton rbt3 = new RadioButton (rbt1, "rbt3");
        VBox vbx1 = new VBox ();
        vbx1.PackStart (rbt1, false, false, 0);
        vbx1.PackStart (rbt2, false, false, 0);
        vbx1.PackStart (rbt3, false, false, 0);
        this.Add (vbx1);
        this.ShowAll ();
        rbt1.Clicked+= HandleClicked;
    rbt2.Clicked+= HandleClicked1;
    rbt3.Clicked+= HandleClicked2;
    }

    void HandleClicked2 (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("rbt3.Clicked");
    }

    void HandleClicked1 (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("rbt2.Clicked");
    }

    void HandleClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("rbt1.Clicked");
    }
 }
```

The issue is:

When i click rbt2, the output is :

> rbt1.Clicked
>   rbt2.Clicked

When i click rbt3, the output is :

> rbt2.Clicked
>   rbt3.Clicked

When i click rbt1, the output is:

> rbt3.Clicked
>   rbt1.Clicked

But what I expect is that when I click rbt*, the only output is "rbt*.Clicked".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expectation is wrong. You should connect to the `Toggled` signal instead and check whether the button is being activated or deactivated:

```
void HandleToggled(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender.Active)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("rbt1.Toggled");
    }
}
```

In your case, the `Clicked` signal is called when the button is activated or deactivated. Clicking on a deactivated button activates it, and deactivates a different button, so two signals are called. The `Toggled` signal is also called in both cases. I'm not quite sure what the difference is, it may be that `Clicked` is not guaranteed to be called if the button's state is changed programmatically.

Comment: Hi,ptomato thanks for your help. And i test Toggled signal as your code, it works. Also i test Clicked signal but added "if((sender as RadionButton).Active)" condition.It also works in my previous code.