# How to check if a radiobutton is selected Monodevelop

Tags: monodevelop, gtk#

I am developing a program in Monodevelop and I have 18 radiobuttons. I want to check which of those buttons is selected.

Comment: What kind of program? GTK#?

Comment: Yes! @LexLi. I try to do with "foreach" if it is possible

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code so we can help answer your question. You might find some hints by looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755541/mono-gtk-radiobutton-clicked-event-firing-twice post.

Comment: GTK# form is a container for child containers and widgets. So you can easily iterate everything via `.Children` property and check if an item is `RadioButton` or not. Trivial things like that can be found out by a few simple experiments.

Comment: Hi all @LexLi , what im trying is something (Im based in C# code): "foreach (Gtk.RadioButton rd in group1.controls)"

Comment: No, GTK# does not have `.Controls`. Don't use your WinForms experience.

Comment: So, can you recommend me a solution @LexLi?

Comment: What I commented earlier can be easily converted to code if you carefully read it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach (Gtk.RadioButton ctrl in table2)
    {
        if (ctrl.Active)
        {
            nome = ctrl.label;
        }
    }
```

considering that the radiobuttons are within table2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).